# checkbox enable/disable from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, checked

I have a question for onclick action.
After clicking the "all" checkbox, `<select>` is blocked, but no "cl" is unchecked.

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="all" name="all" onclick="this.form.elements['oh'].disabled = this.form.elements['cl'].removeAttr('checked') = this.checked">

  <select id="oh" name="oh">
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">oprion 3</option>
  </select>

  <input type="checkbox" id="cl" name="cl">
</form>
```

Comment: Best [to avoid inline handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045), they have a demented scope chain, require global pollution, and have quote escaping issues. Use `addEventListener` instead

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please fix the console errors - I wrapped in form tags to remove one error - you are mixing jQuery functions into DOM coding. `this` is NOT a jQuery object

Comment: There is a lot of wishful coding going on.  Please describe what you WANT to happen instead of posting an X/Y problem

Comment: You can't assign to `.removeAttr('checked')`

Comment: Please also check your browser console for errors.  Browsers these days hide errors unless you have a 3rd party extension.  *"but no "cl" is unchecked"* - but there is an error in the console which explains the issue to you (perhaps not in a way you fully understand yet, but it's explained there - so should be asking "why do I get "removeAttr is not a function" rather than asking why it "does nothing" (paraphrased).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you MIGHT mean this

```js
$("#all").on("click",function() {
  const chk = this.checked;
  $("#oh").prop("disabled",chk)
  $("#cl").prop('checked',!chk)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="all" name="all" />

  <select id="oh" name="oh">
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">oprion 3</option>
  </select>

  <input type="checkbox" id="cl" name="cl">
</form>
```